# Output all txt files in directory that contains a series of regular expression-python

Tags: python, glob

So, I am trying to output all text files in my directory that contains any of several regular expressions.

Here is a sample regular expression that searches for a Phone number in a file

```
#Search for Phone Numbers
regex2 =r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d'
```

Here is my code to get all files, but am confused as to where to put the regex at.

```
import glob

folder_path = "C:\Temp"
file_pattern = "\*.txt"
search_string = "hello"

match_list = []

folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

for file in folder_contents:
    print("Checking", file)
    read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()

    if search_string in read_file:
        match_list.append(file)

print("Files containing search string")
for file in match_list:
    print(file)
```

Here is another method to compiling all txt files in my directory:

```
import glob
import errno
path = '/home//*.txt' #note C:
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            split = line.split()
            if split:
                print(line.split())
```

I tried putting my regex in the if statement in each of the above but gives me errors. Any ideas?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Copy and paste in your question the Traceback you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

# Define your regex
regex2 = re.compile(r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d')

# Read files...

# Check if we have matches in the file content
matches = regex2.findall(read_file)
if matches:
    match_list.append(file)
    print('file:', file)
    print('matches:', matches)
```

Comment: Great, thanks it worked! Now if I wanted to display the match in each file,(so if 248-999-9999 was in a file), would I just create another if loop?

Comment: Have updated the answer accordingly. Also, there's no if loop. for and while loops, and if conditions.

Comment: The updated answer does not provide an output. The unedited one gave the files that the regex matched with.

Comment: Have rolled it back and added a couple of print statements.